# Label.Text / Convert.ToString And String.Format Help / Thousand Separator

Tags: .net, string, format, iformatprovider

I have a label that i want to show it's `Text("1234567")` Like A Number With Thousand Separator//

how can i do this with :

```
Lable1.Text = string.Format(.....;

Lable1.Text = Convet.ToString(.....;
```

please explain these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) information relating to numbers (for use with `Convert.ToString(...,IFormatProvider)`), see the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx). You can follow the links to [NumberGroupSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) and other formatting options which have some example code.

`String.Format` also can take an IFormatProvider, but it also understands other formatting directly supplied as a string. See the remarks section of the [String Format method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) -- once again you can follow the links to areas of interest like [Standard Numerical Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) which has an example of internationalized "," numbers.

Happy reading.

*Addition in response to comment*

IFormatProvider is an interface; [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) is one provider. That is, you can specify the format arguments to a new NumberFormatInfo object and pass that as the IFormatProvider. You can see there is a whole host of members you can twiddle with: [NumberFormatInfo members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo_members.aspx). The advantage of an IFormatProvider is that you can create and define your own conversion formats. You can even invoke the `Format` method of an [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) directly, if you wish -- with some omissions, this is about what `String.Format` does for you. You may also be interested in [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx).

Comment: Relly Reelly Thanks....
but there is no format string in Convert.ToString(...,IFormatProvider))

can u give an example for me here for both of them! (c#)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Num As Integer = 1234567
Label1.Text = Num.ToString("n0")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer / can u give me an example for Convert.ToString in c#!